# Unable to create two tables in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create 2 (and more) tables in SQLite but there is a problem. I created one table before and that is working but now when i try to make a second table and insert some data it is saying 'no such table'

Why is this not working?

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        // create wedstrijden table
        String CREATE_WEDSTRIJD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE wedstrijd ( " +
                "id                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
                "datum              TEXT, " +
                "thuisclub          NUMERIC, " +
                "bezoekers          NUMERIC, " +
                "thuistenue         TEXT, " +
                "bezoekerstenue     TEXT, " +
                "aftrap             TEXT, " +
                "begintijd1ehelft   TEXT, " +
                "eindtijd1ehelft    TEXT, " +
                "extratijd1ehelft   TEXT, " +
                "begintijd2ehelft   TEXT, " +
                "eindtijd2ehelft    TEXT, " +
                "extratijd2ehelft   TEXT, " +
                "verlengen          NUMERIC, " +
                "penalties          NUMERIC, " +
                "begintijdverlengen TEXT, " +
                "eindtijdverlengen  TEXT, " +
                "totalespeeltijd    TEXT, " +
                "begintijdpenalties TEXT, " +
                "eindtijdpenalties  TEXT, " +
                "doelpuntenthuis    NUMERIC, " +
                "doelpuntenuit      NUMERIC)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_WEDSTRIJD_TABLE);

        // create teams table
        String CREATE_TEAM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE teams ( " +
                "id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "naam    TEXT, " +
                "trainer TEXT, " +
                "tenue   TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TEAM_TABLE);

    }
```

And to add data i do this:

```
db.addTeam(new DatabaseTeams(bezoekersTeam,bezoekersTrainer,bezoekersTenue));

public void addTeam(DatabaseTeams team){
// 1. get reference to writable DB
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
// 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_NAAM_TEAM, team.getTeamNaamThuis()); 
values.put(KEY_TRAINER_TEAM, team.getTeamTrainerThuis()); 
values.put(KEY_TENUE_TEAM, team.getTeamTenueThuis()); 
// 3. insert
long lastId = db.insert(TABLE_TEAM, // table
null, //nullColumnHack
values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values
Log.d("Insert new team "+lastId+" invoeren", team.toString());
// 4. close
db.close(); 
}
```

Values are:

```
// Team Info
    // Team table name
    private static final String TABLE_TEAM = "teams";

    // Team table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID_TEAM = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAAM_TEAM = "naam";
    private static final String KEY_TRAINER_TEAM = "trainer";
    private static final String KEY_TENUE_TEAM = "tenue";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS_TEAM = {KEY_ID_TEAM,KEY_NAAM_TEAM,KEY_TRAINER_TEAM,KEY_TENUE_TEAM};
```

Comment: What's the value of `TABLE_TEAM`?

Comment: put your logcat error if u got any crash?

Comment: Once you have created one table and then after if you want to add another table then you need to change the database version otherwise it will always refer to the old database.

Comment: Values are in the question now

Comment: // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; this is what i have now GrlsHu. So i need to increment the version?

Comment: Yes you need to increment the version and then try out.

Comment: if you place that as an answer GrlsHu i can accept your answer. It is working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably that `onCreate()` is not being called.

Every time you change your database structure, you need to increment the database version, which is an int `DATABASE_VERSION` in your SQLiteOpenHelper. You also have to implement `onUpgrade()` correctly, as this is called when Android detects that the database version has been increased. Do it like this:

```java
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // drop old tables
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

See the [android tutorial on creating an sqlite helper](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DbHelper) for a more thorough explanation and code examples.